# Hyperledger Composer: Where is the Open API Specification generated by composer-rest-server stored?

Tags: swagger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, swagger-codegen, openapi

I want to use the specification in to generate a Java client using swagger codegen in order to consume the REST API from a Java application. Where do I find the Open API spec after I start the composer-rest-server? I've tried looking it up but I can't figure out where that file is stored after it is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the docs are at your [localhost:3000/explorer](http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer)

This is generated automatically by the LoopBack framework.

You should carefully follow: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/getting-started-rest-api.html

Comment: Thanks, I actually found the spec at localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json, it would have been useful if they explained that in the getting started documentation.